# Django and Vue: I keep geetting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" in my website

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

I'm doing this project using Vue and Django, but when I run my code, I keep getting this error

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/winter/yellow-jacket-with-no-zipper:1"
```

I kept reloading and waited 30 minutes for this error to go away, but it keeps appearing.
I don't know if there is a problem in my javascript, because I don't have any errors when I run the vue project.

Here's my code I think has the problem.

Back end:

urls.py module in product package:

```
from django.urls import path, include

from product import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('latest-products/', views.LatestProductsList.as_view()),
  path('products/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:product_slug>', views.ProductDetail.as_view()),
]
```

Front end:

Product.vue script:

```
<template>
  <div class="page-product">
    <div class="columns is-multiline">
      <div class="column is-9">
        <figure class="image mb-6">
          <img v-bind:src="product.get_image">
        </figure>

        <h1 class="title">{{ product.name }}</h1>

        <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="column is-3">
        <h2 class="subtitle">Information</h2>

        <p>Price: <strong>{{ product.price }}</strong></p>

        <div class="field has-addons mt-6">
          <div class="control">
            <input type="number" class="input" min="1" v-model="quantity">
          </div>

          <div class="control">
            <a class="button is-dark">Add to Carts</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'Product',
  data() {
    return {
      product: {},
      quantity: 1
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getProduct()
  },
  methods: {
    getProduct() {
      const category_slug = this.$route.params.category_slug
      const product_slug = this.$route.params.product_slug

      axios
        .get(`/api/v1/products/${category_slug}/${product_slug}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.product = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("error")
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Edit:

After some revision, I think the problem is caused by the views.py module in the product package

```
from django.http import Http404

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Product
from .serializers import ProductSerializer

class LatestProductsList(APIView):
  def get(self, request, format=None):
    products = Product.objects.all()[0:4]
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

#I think its this line of code
class ProductDetail(APIView):
  def get_object(self, category_slug, product_slug):
    try:
      return Product.objects.filter(category_slug=category_slug).get(slug=product_slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
      raise Http404

  def get(self, request, category_slug, product_slug, format=None):
    product = self.get_object(category_slug, product_slug)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: The 500 error means your Python code crashed.  Waiting isn't going to change anything, you need to find out why it crashed.  Those first two lines aren't really in the file, are they?

Comment: Tim Roberts, Thank you for informing me. Also, the first two lines of code were a typo.

Comment: Django has a log doesn't it?  That should have a traceback.

Comment: Tim Roberts, that was the first place I checked, but the terminal kept telling me everything was ok and that "no errors were detected" before running the code. But, I have already found the issue and solved it, and you were right, it was an issue within my python code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revision of my code, I found out that I was right. The problem was the views.py module in the product package. It can be seen in the get_object function located in the ProductDetail class.

Original:

```
 class ProductDetail(APIView):
  def get_object(self, category_slug, product_slug):
    try:
      return Product.objects.filter(category_slug=category_slug).get(slug=product_slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
      raise Http404
```

The problem was I needed to add another underscore/underline( this thing: _ ) when defining the category slug, so

```
category_slug=category_slug
```

becomes

```
category__slug=category_slug
```

New version:

```
class ProductDetail(APIView):
      def get_object(self, category_slug, product_slug):
        try:
          return Product.objects.filter(category__slug=category_slug).get(slug=product_slug)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
          raise Http404
```